# How to remove the items word in cart woocommerce?

Tags: wordpress, function, woocommerce

How to remove the items word in cart woocommerce?

See screenshot: [WooCommerce Mini Cart header.php](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ulpse.png)

in fuctions.php

Cart Fragments:

```
if ( ! function_exists( 'agricola_woocommerce_cart_link_fragment' ) ) {
function agricola_woocommerce_cart_link_fragment( $fragments ) {
    ob_start();
    agricola_woocommerce_cart_link();
    $fragments['a.cart-contents'] = ob_get_clean();

    return $fragments;
}
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_add_to_cart_fragments', 
'agricola_woocommerce_cart_link_fragment' );
```

Cart Link

```
if ( ! function_exists( 'agricola_woocommerce_cart_link' ) ) {
function agricola_woocommerce_cart_link() {
    ?>
    <a class="cart-contents" href="<?php echo esc_url( wc_get_cart_url() ); ?>" title="<?php esc_attr_e( 'View your shopping cart', 'agricola' ); ?>">
        <?php
        $item_count_text = sprintf(
            /* translators: number of items in the mini cart. */
            _n( '%d item', '%d items', WC()->cart->get_cart_contents_count(), 'agricola' ),
            WC()->cart->get_cart_contents_count()
        );
        ?>
        <span class="amount"><?php echo wp_kses_data( WC()->cart->get_cart_subtotal() ); ?></span> <span class="count"><?php echo esc_html( $item_count_text ); ?></span>
    </a>
    <?php
}
}
```

Display Header Cart.

```
if ( ! function_exists( 'agricola_woocommerce_header_cart' ) ) {
function agricola_woocommerce_header_cart() {
    if ( is_cart() ) {
        $class = 'current-menu-item';
    } else {
        $class = '';
    }
    ?>
    <ul id="site-header-cart" class="site-header-cart">
        <li class="<?php echo esc_attr( $class ); ?>">
            <?php agricola_woocommerce_cart_link(); ?>
        </li>
        <li>
            <?php
            $instance = array(
                'title' => '',
            );

            the_widget( 'WC_Widget_Cart', $instance );
            ?>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <?php
}
}
```

I already remove `<?php $item_count_text = sprintf( /* translators: number of items in the mini cart. */ _n( '%d item', '%d items', WC()->cart->get_cart_contents_count(), 'agricola' ), WC()->cart->get_cart_contents_count()); ?>` but keep come back with title like '9 items' I want to hide it.

I only want basket icon with price cost.

Answer (score 0):

You can use CSS to hide that particular part. If you can provide the website link, we can help you with the CSS.
OR you can use String Locator plugin to locate the code where it is written inside the files and then you can comment it or remove it from the file itself.
Thanks

Comment: thanks, the site in localhost not live yet, I added `span.count { display: none;}` however in the future I might have like Basket icon with number of items without the word of items how do I do that?

Comment: One way which I can think of is to make changes in the files itself. which I have already mentioned how to find that code. 
you can create a woocommerce folder in your theme and copy paste the file in which you have to make the change so you wont have to edit the plugin files.

Answer (score 0):

Just remove item and items beside %d. like below

```
if ( ! function_exists( 'agricola_woocommerce_cart_link' ) ) {
function agricola_woocommerce_cart_link() {
    ?>
    <a class="cart-contents" href="<?php echo esc_url( wc_get_cart_url() ); ?>" title="<?php esc_attr_e( 'View your shopping cart', 'agricola' ); ?>">
        <?php
        $item_count_text = sprintf(
            /* translators: number of items in the mini cart. */
            _n( '%d', '%d', WC()->cart->get_cart_contents_count(), 'agricola' ),
            WC()->cart->get_cart_contents_count()
        );
        ?>
        <span class="amount"><?php echo wp_kses_data( WC()->cart->get_cart_subtotal() ); ?></span> <span class="count"><?php echo esc_html( $item_count_text ); ?></span>
    </a>
    <?php
}
}
```

**Note: after remove or changing anything with WooCommerce min cart , you are not able to see those change by refreshing a page, you have to update the cart item to check the changed preview.**